# Tensor Inverse in parallel over multiple GPUs using PyTorch

Tags: python, gpu, pytorch

I want to run over multiple GPUs in parallel torch.inverse(), and am not able to.

I saw this post [Matmul on multiple GPUs](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/matmul-on-multiple-gpus/33122) , which goes over the process for matmul. It shows that if you have multiple tensors allocated to each GPU matmul will be run in parallel. I was able to replicate this behavior for matmul but when I try to do the same thing for torch.inverse() it seems to run sequentially when I check "watch nvidia-smi". Also when I replace the torch.inverse() function with the torch fft function I get parallel GPU usage. Any ideas?

```py
import torch

ngpu = torch.cuda.device_count()
# This is the allocation to each GPU.
lis = []
for i in range(ngpu):
    lis.append(torch.rand(5000,5000,device = 'cuda:'+ str(i)))

# per the matmul on multiple GPUs post this should already be in parallel
# but doesnt seem to be based on watch nvidia-smi
C_ = []
for i in range(ngpu):
    C_.append(torch.inverse(lis[i]))
```

Edit: This can be compared to the FFT code(below) and the Matmul code in the link above.

```py
import torch

ngpu = torch.cuda.device_count()
# This is the allocation to each GPU.
lis = []
for i in range(ngpu):
    lis.append(torch.rand(5000,5000,2,device = 'cuda:'+ str(i)))

# per the matmul on multiple GPUs post this should already be in parallel
# but doesnt seem to be based on watch nvidia-smi
C_ = []
for i in range(ngpu):
    C_.append(torch.fft(lis[i],2))
```

Comment: When I run your code, I notice parallel GPU usage. Did you use `watch -n 0.5 nvidia-smi` to watch the gpu usage?

Comment: Yes, I tried this and I still see it happen in series. One can compare this to the result with the fft code that I have edited above.

Comment: I have tried both of two snippets. What I observed is that one GPU occupies memory first and then the second one occupies the memory, both for fft and inverse. Did you observe the two GPUs occupy the memory at the same time for fft?

Comment: No, the data allocation to the GPU happens in series for both. I separate out the GPU allocation and running the actual function via jupyter notebook cells. My issue is that the inverse function is not running in parallel over the multiple GPUs (6 in my case). But that the FFT function and also the matmul are both running in parallel over the GPUs.